# flex-column of bootstrap fills out full width, how to not stretch to full width?

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

see here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#direction

items stretch to full width, but that is not really my desired outcome.

I want the items to keep their original size

what is the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `flex-column` element with a `col-auto` element so that it takes as much space as it needs.

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column bg-highlight mb-3">
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may use a container also.

---

Even better, use a `d-flex` element to wrap the `flex-column` element. But if you do, remove the `d-flex` and `flex-column` classes from the element itself and instead use `w-auto`.

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="w-auto bg-highlight mb-3">
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what I found as well to work was to wrap the text content into a div. By defintion of bootstrap, flex columns always try to be equal size and max size, but not their content at least afaik